# Runtime Exception. Exception in python callback function evaluation:

Tags: python

I am working on an assignment for Coursera's Machine Learning: Regression course. I am using the kc_house_data.gl/ dataset and GraphLab Create. I am adding new variables to train_data and test_data that are combinations of old variables. Then I take the mean of all these variables. These are the variables I am adding:

```
bedrooms_squared = bedrooms * bedrooms

bed_bath_rooms = bedrooms*bathrooms

log_sqft_living = log(sqft_living)

lat_plus_long = lat + long
```

Here is my code:

```
train_data['bedrooms_squared'] = train_data['bedrooms'].apply(lambda x: x**2)
test_data['bedrooms_squared'] = test_data['bedrooms'].apply(lambda x: x**2)
# create the remaining 3 features in both TEST and TRAIN data
train_data['bed_bath_rooms'] = train_data.apply(lambda row: row['bedrooms'] * row['bathrooms'])
test_data['bed_bath_rooms'] = test_data.apply(lambda row: row['bedrooms'] * row['bathrooms'])

train_data['log_sqft_living'] = train_data['sqft_living'].apply(lambda x: log(x))
test_data['log_sqft_living'] = test_data['bedrooms'].apply(lambda x: log(x))
train_data['lat_plus_long'] = train_data.apply(lambda row: row['lat'] + row['long'])
train_data['lat_plus_long'] = train_data.apply(lambda row: row['lat'] + row['long'])
test_data['bedrooms_squared'].mean()
test_data['bed_bath_rooms'].mean()
test_data['log_sqft_living'].mean()
test_data['lat_plus_long'].mean()
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
RuntimeError: Runtime Exception. Exception in python callback function evaluation: 
ValueError('math domain error',): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graphlab\cython\cy_pylambda_workers.pyx", line 426, in graphlab.cython.cy_pylambda_workers._eval_lambda
  File "graphlab\cython\cy_pylambda_workers.pyx", line 169, in graphlab.cython.cy_pylambda_workers.lambda_evaluator.eval_simple
  File "<ipython-input-13-1cdbcd5f5d9b>", line 5, in <lambda>
ValueError: math domain error
```

I have no idea what this means. Any idea on what caused it and how I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `log` is receiving a negative number.

`log` is defined only for numbers greater than zero.

You need to check your values.

Answer (score 0):

Please add/learn exceptions to make your code more robust:

```
try:
    train_data['log_sqft_living'] = train_data['sqft_living'].apply(lambda x: log(x))
    test_data['log_sqft_living'] = test_data['bedrooms'].apply(lambda x: log(x))
    train_data['lat_plus_long'] = train_data.apply(lambda row: row['lat'] + row['long'])
    train_data['lat_plus_long'] = train_data.apply(lambda row: row['lat'] + row['long'])
    test_data['bedrooms_squared'].mean()
    test_data['bed_bath_rooms'].mean()
    test_data['log_sqft_living'].mean()
    test_data['lat_plus_long'].mean()
except e as Exception:
    print "ERROR in function:", e
```